# LLVM IR of OpenCL kernel to PTX to binary

Tags: clang, opencl, llvm, ptx

I am using clang to generate LLVM IR for Nvidia OpenCL and Cuda kernels, which i want to subsequently instrument, doing something like this for OpenCL:

```
clang -c -x cl -S -emit-llvm -cl-std=CL2.0 kernel.cl -o kernel.ll
```

and what's described [here](http://llvm.org/docs/CompileCudaWithLLVM.html) for Cuda.

What i am looking for is a way to go from the instrumented IR to an actual binary. For the case of Cuda i know i can use the NVPTX backend to generate PTX and JIT compile as described [here](http://llvm.org/docs/NVPTXUsage.html?#executing-ptx) (or perhaps use ptxas?). I was wondering if something similar is also possible for the OpenCL case, and if so, perhaps a minimal example. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can in principle extract binaries for loaded and compiled OpenCL kernels by using [`clGetProgramInfo()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clGetProgramInfo.html) with `CL_PROGRAM_BINARY_SIZES` and `CL_PROGRAM_BINARIES`.

As far as I'm aware, this will produce binaries in an entirely implementation-defined format. So if you're unlucky, you just get IR code back anyway. With any luck, it might contain PTX machine code on your platform, however.